# how to link base type variable in JsViews custom tag

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews, spectrumjs

I use [JsViews](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsviews) + [spectrumjs colorpicker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events-move) and i had to create custom tag like this:

```
$.views.tags({
    spectrum : {
        template : "<input/>",
        onAfterLink : function (tagCtx, linkCtx) {
            var tag = this;
            var props = tagCtx.props;
            var options = {
                color : tagCtx.args[0]
            };
            var linkedElem;
            if (tag._.unlinked) {
                if (!tag.linkedElem) {
                    tag.linkedElem = tag._.inline ? tag.contents("*").first() : $(linkCtx.elem);
                }
                linkedElem = tag.linkedElem;
                $.each(props, function (key, prop) {
                    var option;
                    if (key.charAt(0) === "_") {
                        key = key.slice(1);
                        options[key] = prop;
                    }
                });
                this.linkedElem.spectrum(options);
            }
        },
        onUpdate : function () {
            return false;
        },
        onDispose : function () {
            this.linkedElem.spectrum("destroy");
        }
    }
});
```

It works see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/aopqj0c7/2/), but i need to dynamically update color.
In spectrumjs there is event `move.spectrum` and sign up on him like that:

```
tag.spectrum = tag.linkedElem.spectrum(options);
tag.spectrum.on("move.spectrum", $.proxy(tag.moveEvent, tag));
```

And add handlers:

```
moveEvent : function (e, val) {
    // update model.color
    console.log(val.toRgbString());
    this.linkedElem.val(val.toRgbString());
},

onDispose : function () {
    this.spectrum.off("move.spectrum", $.proxy(this.moveEvent, this));
    this.spectrum.spectrum("destroy");
}
```

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/g4vs23v1/4/).
So I have not tried it, I can not track changes or apply changes to `model.color` becose color is base type `string`

**Update**

I made an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/b9mhvrpn/1/) without use custom tag of how things should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update of your example page: https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/g4vs23v1/5/

I changed the onAfterLink code as follows:

```
onAfterLink : function (tagCtx, linkCtx) {
    var tag = this;
    var props = tagCtx.props;
    var options = {
        color: tagCtx.args[0]
    };
    var linkedElem;
    if (tag._.unlinked) {
        if (!tag.linkedElem) {
            tag.linkedElem = tag._.inline ? tag.contents("*").first() : $(linkCtx.elem);
        }
        linkedElem = tag.linkedElem;
        $.each(props, function (key, prop) {
            var option;
            if (key.charAt(0) === "_") {
                key = key.slice(1);
                options[key] = prop;
            }
        });
        tag.spectrum = linkedElem.spectrum(options);
        //tag.spectrum.on("move.spectrum", $.proxy(tag.moveEvent, tag));
        linkedElem.on("move.spectrum", $.proxy(tag.moveEvent, tag));
    } else {
        tag.linkedElem.spectrum("set", options.color);
    }
},
```

Specifically I corrected the binding to move.spectrum as follows

```
linkedElem.on("move.spectrum", $.proxy(tag.moveEvent, tag));
```

And when color is updated observably, such as by changing the `"rgb(...)"` string in the textbox, the new value needs to be set on the spectrum tag, which happens on this line:

```
tag.linkedElem.spectrum("set", options.color);
```

So now you should have two-way binding between the input binding to `color` and the input binding to the `{{spectrum}}` tag.

Comment: Thank you, it helped and i did he wanted to see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/vf64g54u/). But i think your answer will be more complete if you add to it more about the internal methods in tags eg `tag.update` and `tag.refresh` because I did not find the answers [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvtagcontrols).

Comment: Yes, I will be providing some additional documentation topics on custom tag controls in JsViews. There are a few areas of documentation that are still in progress...